# Understanding .removeClass in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can some one please explain to me what exactly is this jQuery call doing

```
   $("header").removeClass("alternative full-width").addClass("full-width");
```

What exactly is it doing to the CSS file, Many Thanks

Comment: what is confusing you?  It seems to attempt to find the `header`, remove some values in the `class` attribute, and then add another value to the `class` attribute.

Comment: have you even bothered to lookup jquery docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removeClass() function will remove the css selector applied to the element. In your case, if the header element has css attribute with value "**alternative full-width**", then those will be removed and it will add "**full-width**"

I also observe that, the above code has two values and you're trying to remove those two and add one of them.

Instead you could do this -

```
$("header").removeClass("alternative");
```

since you wish to add "full-width" which is already available!
**NOTE** I assume the **.full-width** css value is constant in that field. If it's not the case, we may have to use **hasClass()** to determine the existence!

For more info on removeClass - https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: Valid question **Andrei!** I was just showing him the alternate ways. Also, could be possible that, **.full-width** may be constant as the css value and **.alternative** may be an add on based on some logic.

But we have to definitely looks for the existence of the class using **hasClass()** kind of methods and act accordingly!

Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: Simplified version of code in question is `$('header').removeClass('alternative').addClass('full-width')`. That's all. No need to check for anything.

Answer (score -1):

> What exactly is it doing to the CSS file?

It has no effect on the CSS file

> Can some one please explain to me what exactly is this jQuery call
>   doing

it remove the classes ( alternative and full-width )from the header with removeClass() and then it add the class ( full-width  ) with addClass()

Answer (score -2):

Header Element

$("header")
Select a header tag via JQuery
.removeClass("alternative full-width")
This method remove the "alternative full-width" class
.addClass("full-width")
This method add the "full-width" class.
As a matter of fact the JQuery it doesn't do anything in the CSS file.The only thing that is done with this example is  to inherit the class properties that you have alredy define in the css file